# countif unique values using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have read a bunch of other posts, but havent fount what I need. I need to do a countif on 2 criteria, but only count the unique "EventIds" in this case that meet it. currently it counts the total number that meet the criteria

```
EventID     DR Ref(F)   Number Locations (G)
110000018   1           13
110000018   2           2
110000018   3           8
110000018   4           5
110000252   1           3
110000252   2           3
110000354   1           1
110000366   1           2
110000366   3           1
```

I have the data above and am trying to display it in a matrix below, currently I am using a `countif` with `F` being  the `"DR Ref"` column, `"AB"` being `DR1` a

```
=COUNTIFS($F$4:$F$12,">="&AB$2,$G$4:$G$12,">="&$Y4)
```

this is the current output...

```
            DR
Locat    1(AB)  2   3
> 1        9    5   3
> 2        7    4   2
> 3        5    3   2
> 4        3    2   2
> 5        3    2   2
> 6        2    1   1
> 7        2    1   1
> 8        2    1   1
> 9        1    0   0
> 10       1    0   0
> 11       1    0   0
> 12       1    0   0
> 13       1    0   0
```

Desired output

this is the wanted output...

```
            DR
Locat    1(AB)  2   3
> 1        4    3   2
> 2        3    2   1
> 3        2    2   1
> 4        1    1   1
> 5        1    1   1
> 6        1    1   1
> 7        1    1   1
> 8        1    1   1
> 9        1    0   0
> 10       1    0   0
> 11       1    0   0
> 12       1    0   0
> 13       1    0   0
```

Comment: What have you got as criteria in column Y? We need to understand properly what kind of count you are trying to get.

Comment: Sorry, column Y would be the location , so 1,2,3,4,5 etc, .. its the column in the results matrix

Comment: I found an answer using a countunique and filter formula in google spreadsheets, but would like to have it in my excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
=SUM(IF(($F$4:$F$12>=AB$2)*($G$4:$G$12>=$Y4),1/COUNTIFS($E$4:$E$12,$E$4:$E$12,$F$4:$F$12,">="&AB$2,$G$4:$G$12,">="&$Y4),0))
```

and press ctrl+shift+enter
[image: formula should look like below]

Check the code [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15mx7Kxyl04h3amu7knOuIiTdHzXBov40089xG5ZEUoA/edit?usp=sharing).

but I have to say that you phrased the question in a very typical manner.